# Run commands on Raspberry Pi when external HDD is connected

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am using a Raspberry Pi to provide network access to a Western Digital media player that has no network interface. The player if just an external HDD and automatically mounts when it is connected.

The problem is that it's HFS formatted, so to be able to read and write it I have to unmount and then remount it with these commands:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda2
sudo mount -o force -t hfsplus /dev/sda2 /media/wdhdd/
```

Which works fine, but I don't want to have to SSH in via terminal to run these manually every time I reconnect the HDD.

Is there anyway to auto run a script when an external USB device is mounted?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757856/run-command-after-mount-unmout-usb-pen-drive

Answer (score 1):

Because this has to be done every time this USB device is plugged in, you should edit the procedures done when it is plugged in. You can find out more about this by visiting [this explanation](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-502864.html)